# will this be beneficial for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently taken the Ruby on Rails course at One month Rails and All though I completed the course I am unsure of a lot of the code that I used.

Just wanting to know if you guys think doing this https://teamtreehouse.com/tracks/learn-ruby will get me back on track in understanding the code in Ruby on rails.

Thanks in advance!.

Cheers,

Kamal

Comment: Please review this article for appropriate questions to ask here http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I think understanding Ruby on its own to a reasonable level is important. There are lots of good resources out there, such as (in order): codecademy; the book Learn to Program by Chris Pine; the book Beginning Ruby by Peter Cooper; the book: The Well-grounded Rubyist by David A. Black. That should get you get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Rails is a bog framework to be learned in a matter of 1 week, the treehouse course for rails isnt really gonna be efficient its a little advanced, you can take a look at **codeacademy** , or **codeschool**, or the book of **Michael Hartl: learning ruby on rails**. Give it time, focus, and attention no need to burn things up otherwise your knowledge wont be solid and structured. Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. So you think that having a good foundation of ruby first should do the trick ? I am going to do codeacadamy ruby then move on the Michael Hartl's book.  truth is I tried Michael Hartl's book on rails however I did not really understand a lot of the code :|

Comment: You dont really need to go on all ruby langage, really just the baasics would be enough ( variables, conditionals, loops, arrays, hashes, functions ), even the best programmers needs to look into the ruby api documentation alongside coding. If am not wrong Michael dedicated a chapter, 4 I beleive, for the needs to know in ruby. And its fine if hou dt get things clearly from the first time, by using t and digging here and there you ll get a lot. And also you have to practise along with whatever course or book you re taking.  You re welcome anytime

Comment: Thanks Boss! appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Also a very good source is [pragmatic studio](https://pragmaticstudio.com/courses/rails). I took the course myself and learned a lot.

Micheal Hartls book also has an accompanying [screen cast](https://www.railstutorial.org/#pricing). I think this is especially useful because Micheal didn't cut out issues he comes across during development. It's like looking over his shoulder while he is programming.